# Can I create an Area in an Existing ASP.NET MVC 5 App that uses Angular.js?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an existing MVC 5 app that was created without Angular.

I would like to build some new functionality as a single page style app utilizing angular.

Can I do this within an Area to keep everything separate and organized outside of the existing app?

Comment: Asking for tutorials isn't allowed on Stack Overflow. And why don't you just try doing what you described instead of asking an overly broad "what can go wrong?" type question?

Comment: If the question is can you do this, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The awnser is yes. Try this lab: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-(spa)-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You can use how much or how little of Angular in your application as you want. It can be all encompassing, managing your routes on the frontend, or it could be a small directive if so be it. Though, people usually use Angular as the main, and not some side thing, the cost and complexity doesn't exactly necessitate Angular if you're just using a small subset of it.